# RegAsm failing for a .NET 4.0 assembly using Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, async-await, regasm

RegAsm failing for a .NET 4.0 assembly using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` with the following message:

```
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 
'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match 
the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

My assembly (`MyAssembly.dll`) uses the latest `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package, here's the project's `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.6" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.165" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.13" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

It bundles `System.Threading.Tasks.dll` Version: 2.6.6.0 which is a part of that NuGet package. There is no other `System.Threading.Tasks.dll` on the target system (Win7 with .NET 4.0 but without .NET 4.5), neither in GAC nor anywhere else.

Here is `MyAssembly.dll.config`, it has correct `bindingRedirect` elements for `System.Threading.Tasks`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.6.0" newVersion="2.6.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.6.0" newVersion="2.6.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.6.0" newVersion="2.6.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

My question: **does RegAsm not use `MyAssembly.dll.config`? How do I make it work so it resolves `bindingRedirect` instructions?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I have come up with is a hack:

- copied `RegAsm.exe` and `RegAsm.exe.config` from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe` to a local folder where `MyAssembly.dll` is;
- edited `RegAsm.exe.config` to look like this:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <requiredRuntime safemode="true" imageVersion="v4.0.30319" version="v4.0.30319"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku="client" />
    </startup>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.6.0" newVersion="2.6.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.6.0" newVersion="2.6.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.6.0" newVersion="2.6.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

- now, running `RegAsm.exe /codebase MyAssembly.dll` works fine as expected.

Interestingly, `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"` has already been there in the standard `RegAsm.exe.config`, but alone it did not help.

I think this is the same bug reported here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789318/asyncpack-system-io-fileloadexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-threading-tasks-version-1-5-11-0.

Comment: Nice work - thanks for this. The version number is now 2.6.8.0 but this works fine.