# Using Microsoft.Bcl.Async I get the warning "Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM.NET'" in my installer

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, installation, async-await

I am using the [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects Preview](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) with a project that uses [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/). When the installer builds I get the following warning

> WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM.NET' (Signature='7CEC85D7BEA7798E' Version='2.0.5.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll'

Checking my project I see that installing Bcl.Async adds a reference to System.Net but it is the 4.0.0.0 version.

[image]

Removing the reference and doing a `update-package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -Reinstall` just re-adds the 4.0.0.0 version of the assembly. Looking at some of the other assemblies it adds, like `System.Runtime`, all have a version of `2.6.8.0` instead of 4.0.0.0 like most other framework assemblies in my project.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in either the installer preview or Bcl.Async?

Comment: These are retargetable assembly versions, it powers PCL class libraries.  They get mapped to the actually available assembly at runtime.  But that of course should not happen in an installer.  It is an alpha quality preview, things are expected to go wrong.  Post the bug to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: I figured that was what it was but was not sure. That is why I ended it with "is it my bug or theirs". Can you post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I don't like to post answers to alpha quality software questions, it is a waste of my time since the answer stops being useful in a matter of weeks.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Just a FYI for the installer project they want you to report bugs to the Q and A page of the package instead of connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the installer project package, I have reported the bug to their Q and A section and hopefully will be fixed in a later version.

Comment: Is it possible to specify explicit `bindingRedirect` entries for the installer `.config` file, similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20135641/1768303)?

Comment: Don't know, after coming to the realization that how early in development the installer project module is I decided to just bite the bullet and learn [WiX](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/).